# CSS fluid layout without tables

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

Everything online points me to stop using tables, which I've tried my best to do, but I've come across a problem which tables seems to be the only solution for.  I have 5 inline-block elements that I want spaced evenly across 100% of the width of the page.  I put a width of 20% on the style and set the margin and padding to zero.  When I view the page, everything looks pretty good except for the horizontal scrollbar added to the page.  If I put these elements in a 100% width table with 5 columns this isn't a problem.  In this case do I need to use a table or is there a better solution?

BTW, I've tried this in both Chrome and IE8.

Update:  Something I've discovered is that a ~5px gap is being inserted between my elements (found by putting a background-color on them).  I have no clue why, as nothing in my styles denotes this:

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="#">Previous</a>
    <a href="#">Current</a>
    <a href="#">Next</a>
    <a href="#">01/01/2011</a>
    <a href="#">01/08/2011</a>
</div>
```

.links
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.links a
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: White;
    background-color: #4C8331;
}

Another update:

After JMC Creative pointed out my dumb mistake of putting spaces between the anchors that almost fixed the issue, but now there is one pixel of scrollbar.  I see no inherited style that should cause this.

Comment: This is a hack, but you could make each box 19.5% and make the '.links' margin: 0 auto which would center it on the page.

Comment: It looks like the 1px scroll might be an IE-only issue?  In Chrome and BlackBerry browser there's no scrollbar.

Comment: You could simply set ` overflow: hidden ` in the css, or make it an IE only rule (see my edited answer below)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting them in a container. Like so:

```
#container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#boxes {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Maybe more like .boxes instead of #boxes

Comment: This causes the last link to fall below the rest.  I don't want line breaks, which is why I made them inline-block and put whitespace nowrap on the container.  Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 2):

Your html markup has a space in between the a tags. So therefore it's being rendered as 5 blocks which are 20% wide and 4 spaces of roughly 4px each.  So you end up with 100% + 16px.

#### Edit

In order to solve the scrollbar that is plaguing you in IE, you could set up a conditional comment like so:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css"> .links { overflow: hidden; } </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That helped, but there's still a slight scroll, though not as heavy.

Comment: Maybe we need to see more code.  The code we've got so far works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/7G97D/1/

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your body and html set to `margin: 0; padding: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using overflow: hidden? Or more specifically overflow-y: hidden?

Comment: This almost works, but for some reason a ~5px gap is being put between my elements.  I wonder if this is why I'm having the problem in the first place...

Comment: Have you checked the styles in firebug to see if they are inheriting any other margin styles?

Answer (score 0):

You want to float your anchors. Doing it this way [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/KVnhx/).

CSS:

```
.links {
    width: 100%;
}

.links>a {
    float: left;   
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4C8331;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="#">Previous</a>
    <a href="#">Current</a>
    <a href="#">Next</a>
    <a href="#">01/01/2011</a>
    <a href="#">01/08/2011</a>
</div>
```

You may get a scrollbar or see some of the anchors wrapped to another line if there isn't room to fit them all on the page (ie, content overflows the width). I will note that I have seen IE get this wrong and incorrectly wrap when it shouldn't. It seems like a rounding issue and could be worked around.